# how to unit test a route that redirects to a static file in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing, routes

I setup a route that redirect to a static file and i would like to write a test using unit test for it
----- the route ------
get '/users/sign_in', :to => redirect("/404.html")

Any idea ?

Comment: actually none yet. i can tell you i gave up on :to though and started using redirect.  I will come back with the answer soon i hope.